# Hooking into comment_text() to add surrounding tag

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, hook, add-filter

Trying to hook into the function [comment_text()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/comment_text) supplied by Wordpress API to wrap the output of every comment into a `<div>...</div>` container I am running into the following problem:

Without my added filter the output of [comment_text()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/comment_text) looks like this:

```
<p>Hello User!</p>
<p>Thank you for your comment.</p>
<p>Stefan</p>
```

Thats fine but as I said I would like to have it wrapped into a `<div class="comment-text">...</div>`. As far as I know the correct way doing this would be in adding a filter to `functions.php` of my theme and so I did:

```
function stefan_wrap_comment_text($content) {
    return "<div class=\"comment-text\">". $content ."</div>";
}
add_filter('comment_text', 'stefan_wrap_comment_text');
```

As I can see from the output the given filter works but it has a negative sideeffect to the first paragraph of the content as you can see in the following example. The first paragraph should be `<p>Hello User!</p>` but looks like this: `Hello User!`.

```
<div class="comment-text">
    Hello User!
    <p>Thank you for your comment.</p>
    <p>Stefan</p>
</div>
```

Any ideas or hints what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to lower the priority of your function, maybe there is some formatting function which you precede.

```
add_filter('comment_text', 'stefan_wrap_comment_text', 1000);
```

Comment: @Ivo: Thanks, you are absolutely right. I already found the solution and wrote an answer to my question so that others may have the chance to solve this problem more quickly than me.

Answer (score 7):

Ouch, just stumbled over the file `wp-includes/default-filters.php` and found out that there are several filters applied to the same function per default:

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wptexturize'            );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'convert_chars'          );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'make_clickable',      9 );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'force_balance_tags', 25 ); 
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'convert_smilies',    20 );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpautop',            30 );
```

The last filter with priority 30 calls the function [wpautop()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) that is used for replacing double line breaks with `<p>...</p>`. Per default [add_filter()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) registers new filters on priority 10. Changing my filter to be the last by choosing a higher number everything works fine.

```
// This doesn't work because default priority is 10:
// add_filter('comment_text', 'stefan_wrap_comment_text');
// Add a lower priority (higher number) to apply this filter at last: 
add_filter('comment_text', 'stefan_wrap_comment_text', 99);
```